# Configuration Error on initializeData="<app root directory>\Asptesttrace.log" />

Tags: asp.net

I am following the Walkthrough: Integrating ASP.NET Tracing with System.Diagnostics Tracing document and when I get the section on Routing All Tracing Output to .NET Framework Tracing it said to add the following the to the trace section in the  web.config

```
<add name="TestTracer" 
        type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener, System, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" 
        initializeData="<app root directory>\Asptesttrace.log" />
```

The  `initializeData="<app root directory>\Asptesttrace.log" />` part is giving a compile error.
In visual studio the it said the  app root and directory part need tags. 
When  run the default.aspx page there error shown in the webpae is

### Server Error in '/' Application.

Configuration Error 
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

```
Parser Error Message: '<', hexadecimal value 0x3C, is an invalid attribute character. Line 25, position 27.

Source Error: 


Line 23:         <add name="TestTracer"
Line 24:           type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener, System, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
Line 25:           initializeData="<app root directory>\Asptesttrace.log" />
Line 26:       </listeners>
Line 27:     </trace>
```

Of I am stumped what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Can you see that you have break the [xml format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) ? You can not add this

```
<app root directory>
```

inside the the tag, you break the xml format.

Remove the  and if you have permission to write, its going to work

```
<add name="TestTracer" 
        type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener, System, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" 
        initializeData="Asptesttrace.log" />
```

Reference: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.textwritertracelistener.aspx

`<app root directory>` : this is the part that you need to change by hand, and type your application root path, if that was visual studio says, but its not a parameter that find its. Eg:  c:\inetpub\vhost\yoursite.com\httpfiles\Asptesttrace.log